# Array empty is very slow

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm just wondering why iterate a array empty it's slow compared with a filled array.

```
for (var items=9999,arr=[],arr2=[],i=0; i<items; ++i)
    arr.push(true);

arr2[items-1] = true;
arr.length == arr2.length; // true
```

Iterating filled:

```
for (i=0; i<items;i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== undefined)
            arr[i];
} //107,600 Ops/sec
```

Iterating empty:

```
for (i=0; i<items;i++) {
    if (arr2[i] !== undefined)
            arr2[i];
} //689 Ops/sec
```

Can someone give me a explain of this?
http://jsperf.com/iterating-for-loop-normal-and-undefined

Comment: Your second array is sparse. Chances are item access in the first, non-sparse array is optimized (lookup by index, O(1) complexity), but item access in the sparse array requires a key lookup (O(log n)) on every iteration.

Comment: And the first array is homogenous, containing only booleans, and thus can be stored and accessed in a fast optimized way (at least by V8).

Comment: this is a tricky issue having to do with how various browsers handle un-initialised arrays (or uninitialised values in general). One point is that an initialised value has been parsed and in a sense already compiled, profiled, boxed or unboxed and optimised. While unitialised values are in a state of *generic state* which will need further boxing/unboxing when an actual value is assigned etc..

Comment: take a look this: http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/em63ardh/  The `arr3` has length 9999 but contains no items, so probably java script is not optimize for this kind of situations.